# Armadillo code which is the same as MATLAB code but much slower

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, armadillo

Recently I need to convert matlab code to c++. It includes matrix operations so I use Armadillo.But it turned out that Armadillo is much slower and I wonder why.
Here's the matlab code:

```
for j=1:sample
    for i=1:length(t)
        k=[1:1:N0];
        AA=sqrt(2*k*dw).*(cos(dw.*k*i*dt).*Xk(j,k)+sin(dw.*k*i*dt).*Yk(j,k));
        Ag2(i)=sum(AA); 
    end
    Ag(j,:)=Ag2.*gt;
end
```

Here's the Armadillo code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sample; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < t.n_cols; i++){
            AA = sqrt(2 * k * dw)
                % (cos(dw * k * (i + 1) * dt) % Xk.row(j) + sin(dw * k * (i + 1) * dt) % Yk.row(j));
            Ag2(i) = sum(AA);
        }
        Ag.row(j) = Ag2 % gt;
    }
```

where Xk,Yk,Ag,Ag2 are matrices, AA,k are vectors and others are double.
Matlab code runs for 20s and Armadillo code runs for 380s.
Anybody got any idea?Your help is really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: did you enable compiler optimization? how did you measure? what is the size of the matrices? Without a [mcve] it is hard (if not impossible) to know why the timings are what you claim they are

Comment: In MATLAB's defense, the kinds of operations that MATLAB supports have been finely optimized to perform those operations well.

Comment: @Eljay it is c++ that would need some defense here ;)

Comment: @user463035818 • :-)  I was just trying to help shed some light on the (unexpected) performance discrepancy.  I think of programming languages as tools, and some tools are better suited for certain domains than other tools.  MATLAB does a fine job in the MATLAB domain; trying to get a C++ program to be as good as MATLAB in the MATLAB domain is not easy.  (I've done a lot of porting of MATLAB code to C# code, which has a similar amount of pain.)

Comment: @user463035818 Sadly I just found out that I didn't enable compiler optimization when I used the debug mode. So I turned it on and found out the time cost twice as matlab code's which is acceptable for me.So maybe I just need to do a little more job.Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Matlab code shows a lot of vector operations inside the 2 for loops. Matlab does a good job multithreading.

Comment: @doug - Enable OpenMP when compiling Armadillo C++ code. This will enable multi-threading for cos(), sin(), etc, if these functions are used on vectors/matrices. With the gcc compiler, you can also enable auto-vectorization with `-O3`